# How to store the location when an image is clicked?

Tags: android, camera, gps

I am working on an application, where in i have to take some pictures from the android camera and i need to store both image and the location of that image where it was clicked in server through web services. So please help me in completing this task successfully.

Comment: What's your server API? Have you code to make image and get gps coordinates?

Comment: No, now i have started working on it. through soap the interaction happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for making photo:

```
public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }  
    } 
}
```

This is a [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity).

As for getting gps coordinates, you should use `LocationListener`:

```
public class MyCurrentLoctionListener implements LocationListener {

public String myLocation;
private TextView mTextView;

MyCurrentLoctionListener(TextView tv) {
    this.mTextView = tv;    
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

    mTextView.setText("Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude = " + location.getLongitude());

}
```

This is a [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664628/get-current-coordinates-android).

As for transfer data on server, I can suggest you to use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for REST API. If there is no REST API, use provided API of your service.